# Create field of type Business data with the object model

Tags: 2007, business-data-catalog

How can I create a Business Data catalog field with the object model?
So I want to create a field that utilities business data catalog and not add an item to an already existing list.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be a bit more precise. BDC fields are used in many places and can be defined in many ways: application definitions, user profiles, lists, lobsystems in web parts etc.

below is an example on how to instantiate a BDC field in an SPList, as this is something that usually causes a bit of trouble:

```
SPListItem item = someList.Items.Add();

// assign fields
..
item["MyProductID"] = EntityInstanceIdEncoder.EncodeEntityInstanceId(new object[]{"1234"}); // this could also be an integer 
..
item.Update();// alternatively use SystemUpdate
```

Comment: What I meant was that I want to create a list with the object model and then add a field to the list which is a Business Data Catalog field. So I want to add a field and not and item to the list.

Comment: Havent tested this myself, but found another question with answer on Microsoft forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointbdc/thread/33af1fab-2b35-481f-baf1-94f5c1e490ca
You add field using AddFieldAsXml() and the xml definition for the field, and then connect it as a BusinessDataField using system instance, entity and field.